# Empty space character after re.split

Tags: python, regex, split, expression

Here's a line from a `.txt` file I'm reading in, and I'm assigning it to `x`:

```
x = "Wild_lions live mostly in “Africa”"
result = re.split('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', x)
```

I end up getting:

```
['Wild', 'lions', 'live', 'mostly', 'in', 'Africa', ''] # (there's an empty space character as the last element)
```

Why is there an empty space at the end? I realize I can just do `result.remove(' ')` to get rid of the space, but for large files I think this would be pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use this complex regex to split by it, the simpler is:

```
result = re.split('\s+', x)
result
# ['Wild_lions', 'live', 'mostly', 'in', '“Africa”']
```

The [`\s+`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) will match any number of any whitespaces (tabs, spaces, newlines etc).

---

In case you need only alphabetical match, it's better to use [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.compile) with [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall).

```
myre = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+')
myre.findall(x)
# ['Wild', 'lions', 'live', 'mostly', 'in', 'Africa']
```

Comment: But for that example, I want the _ taken out of wild_lions, and the quotes taken off of Africa. Essentially, I want the output to be exactly like: ['Wild_lions', 'live', 'mostly', 'in', 'Africa', ''] without the last space character.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I also figured out another way to do it using re.sub. What I did was replace all special characters with empty spaces, then split it. Would this be a more effective approach? :)

Comment: @dppham1, no, because after you do `re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', s)`, you need to strip the whitespaces and then split. 3 steps vs. this 1 single step. Please accept this solution.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
x = "Wild_lions live mostly in 'Africa'"
result = re.split('[\s_]+', x)
```

You'll get:

```
['Wild', 'lions', 'live', 'mostly', 'in', "'Africa'"]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without having the single quotes around Africa?

Comment: maybe try this
    `result = filter(None, re.split("[\s_']+", x))`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` splits the provided string on any character or sequences of characters that are not digits or ASCII letters.

The final character in the example string matches the split pattern. `re.split` adds the substrings before and *after* the match (up to the next match or end of string) to its output.  In this case, the *after* substring is the empty string, hence the reported output.

Other answers have provided workarounds to get the behaviour that you want so I won't repeat them in this answer.